# is my ionic app scss an old version?

Tags: ionic-framework

the last time I used Ionic was like a year ago. Now I create a new proyect but I realize that all teh css components of ionic had changed but if a try to use something new I cant because I think i'm using an old version.

For instance - this code, I took it from the official docs:

```
  <button ion-button color="secondary">Secondary</button>
  <button ion-button color="danger">Danger</button>
  <button ion-button color="dark">Dark</button>
```

and they show up like plane buttons without style.

But if I write them as I used to, just works.

```
  <button class="button button-positive">
      Boton prueba 2
  </button>
```

The thing is as Ionic changed their docs I don't have any reference now to look out so I don't have another alternative to update. Going nuts to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Ionic v1 or v2+ ?

Comment: Yea I realize I am using V1 and the documentation is for v2... I mean Ionic not even clarified that. What happen with the ppl who wants to use V1? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: They used to put a v2 icon near the top... Nowadays I think you can only tell if it's v1 documentation (but not if it's v2) by such an icon (and the url).